# MySQL - Select rows greater than timestamp AND specific UUID?

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to be able to get the 4 rows above the `**` marked row in the table below from the following query:

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE created_at > '2018-04-19 23:56:35' 
  AND id = '01H5E4sUTlwV2yk2cdGlodr3MBf8acABsfBb'

| id                                    | title        | created_at
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 001w2cwfoqzp8F3Gf6jCwITgNRtvHiBvmdwb  | My Post      | 2018-04-20 02:43:20
| 0CVgGz5kUESVJmG4LYIFW2EHtjzKnEClfoPR  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:35
| 0A1O9Vjg6GwrcNBzi46zxbysSuRIDeIXKMku  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:35
| 03mMiy5iQ3sGD8efpTArxvaqakoQkG21WC2r  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:35
**| 01H5E4sUTlwV2yk2cdGlodr3MBf8acABsfBb  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:35
| 01Rm9WTLkcce5qcRLBWlpwIALItKMixnjhu6  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:35
| 03bBfzdaXCc13lLVIOjgCvYUUl3bKtkaz1za  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:35
| 01A3ulgrx3rvH5nB5DdzYNe8CBc8vf7rEjWJ  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:34
| 00Ipdlt48PPzgERSOXbloi71qYTUB5ulHifR  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:34
| 02klLu3OfyDYmlEgN7usy2esHVV1UUJF65FP  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:34
| 04WXSHIUVLhsbjwMAa78aW7rw6nYUV8HTusN  | My Post      | 2018-04-19 23:56:34
```

I know it can be easily done on the `id`  if it's an integer instead of a `uuid`. But is there any way to do it with the `uuid` and `timestamp` combo since my query didn't return any rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `'2018-04-19 23:56:35' > '2018-04-19 23:56:35'` is always going to be false.  This is because `2018-04-19 23:56:35` is equal to `2018-04-19 23:56:35` and will never be greater than itself, try this instead:

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE created_at >= '2018-04-19 23:56:35'
```

You want the greater than or equal operator, `>=`, instead of the greater than operator, `>`.

You don't need the id field in your WHERE caluse since it appears to be a column with unique values it is always going to return only one record assuming you have a unique index on that column.

Comment: Well, the reason I am using it was for the `id` and `timestamp` to act as a `cursor` for pagination on a big table. So `>=` wouldn't work, and the `id` is needed for that purpose.

Comment: The `id` column would still be returned with the query above since you are doing a `SELECT *` all columns in the table are going to be returned in the resultset.

Comment: A `>=` would have made more sense. The reason why it works with the `>` is that the literal date `'2018-04-19 23:56:35'` is internally represented as `'2018-04-19 23:56:35.000'`, whereas the dates in the actual rows have some non-zero millisecond value which is not shown, (because our tools have a long tradition of lying to us in all sorts of creative ways,) so the literal is (almost) always **less** than the actual row values.